# SharePoint Web Service FileCreationInformation content string parameter

Tags: c#, angularjs, sharepoint

I built my first post api, which passes a string parameter.
The string param contains some config text, which should be uploaded in a subfolder in the style library.

To upload a file I use FileCreationInformation, this works great.
But i cannot use the string parameter, because i will get an exception as follows:

```
angular.js:14642 Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Illegal characters in path.","ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentException","StackTrace":"   at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean checkAdditional)\r\n
```

Here is the controller code:

```
       [HttpPost]
    [Impersonation]
    [Route("default")]
    public void PostDefaultConfig ([FromBody]string config)
    {
        utility.SetDefaultConfig(config);
    }
```

Method code:

```
               public DefaultConfig SetDefaultConfig(string config)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(config))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Config is invalid", nameof(config));
        }

        string myFile = @"D:\DATALOSS_WARNING_README.txt";
        string LibraryName = "Style Library";
        string siteUrl = "http://xxx/sites/dashboard-nick";
        using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
        {
            FileCreationInformation fcInfo = new FileCreationInformation
            {
                Url = Path.Combine("Style Library/SWITCOM.Dashboard/config/", Path.GetFileName(myFile)),
                Overwrite = true,
                Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(config)
            };

            Web myWeb = ctx.Web;
            List myLibrary = myWeb.Lists.GetByTitle(LibraryName);
            myLibrary.RootFolder.Files.Add(fcInfo);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        };
        var test = new DefaultConfig
        {
            Response = "..."
        };
        return test;

    }
```

AngularJS calls the http request as follows:

```
            $http.post($scope.config.HTTP_SERVICE + $scope.config.POST_CONFIG_CHANGE, JSON.stringify(text)).then(function successCallback(response) {
            console.log('Erfolgreich!');
        });
```

And text is like:

```
"var config_data = angular.module('config', []).constant('CONFIG', {\n'PATH_STYLE_LIBRARY' : 'http://xxx/sites/dashboard',\n'PATH_MY_SITE' : 'http://xxx/my',\n'LANG' : 'ENU',\n'SEARCH_URL' : '../../search/Pages/siteresults.aspx',\n'TASKS_URL_ENU' : '/Pages/Tasks.aspx',\n'TASKS_URL_DEU' : '/Seiten/Tasks.aspx',\n'DEFAULT_SITE_IMG' : '../Style%20Library/SWITCOM.Dashboard/images/sharepoint.png',\n'ITEMS_PER_PAGE' : '15',\n'TASKS_LIST_URL_ENU' : '/Lists/Tasks',\n'TASKS_LIST_URL_DEU' : '/Lists/Aufgaben',\n'DOCUMENTS_URL_ENU' : '/Shared Documents',\n'DOCUMENTS_URL_DEU' : '/Freigegebene Dokumente',\n'CALENDAR_URL_ENU' : '/Lists/Calendar',\n'CALENDAR_URL_DEU' : '/Lists/Kalender',\n'CONTACTS_URL' : '/Lists/Contacts',\n'IMAGES_URL' : '/PublishingImages',\n'LINKS_URL' : '/Lists/Links',\n'RECYCLE_BIN_URL' : '/_layouts/15/RecycleBin.aspx',\n'HTTP_SERVICE' : 'http://xxx',\n'GET_BUSINESSAREA' : '/api/businessarea',\n'GET_SITES' : '/api/site',\n'POST_SITES' : '/api/siterequest',\n'GET_STORAGE' : '/api/site/storage',\n'GET_MEMBERS' : '/api/site/members',\n'GET_FOLDERS' : '/api/site/folders',\n'POST_CONFIG_CHANGE' : '/api/site/default',\n'NO_SENDING' : '0',\n'IS_SENDING' : '1',\n'SUC_SENDING' : '2',\n'ERR_DATES_SENDING' : '3',\n'ERR_SERVICE_SENDING' : '4',\n'TEAM_SITE' : 'TEAM-SITE',\n'PROJECT_SITE' : 'PROJECT-SITE',\n'LCID' : '1031',\n'TIMEZONEID' : '4'\n});"
```

I want to use the string config as my content to upload it to my sharepoint as xxx.js.
How is that possible without storing a file on the local hard disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got one solution by try and error.

If someone has got the same or nearly the same "issue", here is my solution.

You have to add encoding and afterwards read the result with MemoryStream

(e.g.):

```
string configText = (string)config["Text"];
byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(configText);
MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);
```